# How to build a drag and drop web-application with connected database?

Tags: javascript, html, database, web-applications, drag-and-drop

For a school project, my main project actually, I am intending to write **a drag & drop web application for a website**. This application is supposed to help users create a character out from predefined models and sets of clothing.

A typical user-interaction would be to first choose a naked character, male or female, then after a short animation be presented with a choice of clothing for that character and so forth.

The application needs to be hooked up to a database where the choices of characters, clothing and other choices / data are stored. This is important as the application needs to be expandable.

An example of a application like this would be: [Incredibox](http://www.incredibox.com/v4/).

What I need help with:

I need to choose and find a framework or guide for writing a application such as this. I need to decide what coding language this can most easily be done in (preferably from the ones I already know).

I have experience with the following:

- HTML and CSS
- Jquery and JavaScript
- MySQLi, PHP and SQL
- Very little ajax

Any help, suggestions or links to such will be greatly appreciated! A link to a guide to a similar application would be fantastic or just words of advice, anything.

Answer (score 0):

if you're interesting in meteor , you can try.
meteor has a browser mini mongodb, and it's sync to server mongodb ,everything change on server will be sent to browser , and changes on local will also sync to server . no manual ajax needed